# Android - ActionBar Compat Style

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

In my app I'm using the ActionBarCompat `Theme.AppCompat` (like holo but backwards compatable) style but I'd like to use the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` style for the action bar only.

So far I've tried numerous things in xml,

`<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse</item>`

but it doesn't change the ActionBar at all.
Any Suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse</item>
```

first line for preICS platforms, second for ICS. or you can split this style between values and values-v14 folders

Comment: this works, but the title text is black. i need the test to be white so it is legible. ant ideas?

Comment: @David creatre actionbar title style:
 `<style name="ActionBarTitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_title_color</item>
    </style>`
and after that add this style to your actionbar style:
`<style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle</item>
    </style>`